# Jim/The Human Torch in Secret Avengers?

Tags: comics, marvel, avengers

I just read Secret Avengers #25 and am a bit confused about the Jim/Human Torch/robot character.  [In the Marvel wiki](http://marvel.com/universe/Human_Torch_%28Johnny_Storm%29), the Human Torch is called Johnny Storm and is listed as part of the Secret Avengers.  In #25, the others are calling him Jim and he appears to be some kind of robot.  What am I missing?

Disclaimer: This is what I get for jumping in part way through.  Blame the [comics grant](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/970/ongoing-comic-book-grant-updated-apr-2-2012). ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Human Torch in Secret Avengers (and also in the current Captain America and Bucky arc) is the "original" Human Torch - [Jim Hammond](http://marvel.com/universe/Human_Torch_%28Jim_Hammond%29) - originally published by Timely Comics

Jim was an android created by Phineas T Horton and is often regarded as the original Marvel super hero - and along with Cap, Bucky and Namor fought in WWII as The Invaders.

By the time Stan and Jack created Marvel Comics proper with the Fantastic Four the original torch hadn't been published for some time.

Comment: So there's two Human Torches... Way to confuse me!

Comment: @dlanod and they're both part of the Secret avengers?

Comment: @Pureferret I'm guessing the Marvel Wiki has the wrong one in the Secret Avengers, as Hammond doesn't have the Secret Avengers in his group affiliations.

Comment: I've not read the Secret Avengers in question, but looking around it appears that it is Jim Hammond in that case.  Marvel Wiki is a bit out of date.  Johnny Storm (the modern human torch) is normally associated with the Fantastic Four

Comment: If you really want to be confused, it was believed that the Vision was actually the body of the Human Torch (Jim Hammond) retooled by Ultron as the underlying hardware for the Vision. It was only when Marvel decided to bring back the Original Human Torch did they decide that the Vision was actually an original design of Ultron's. Everyone was confused for a time.